# Firefox WebExtension, how to open "Chrome://*" URLS in a new Tab?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to set hotkeys to open links to a bunch of useful pages like

```
chrome://browser/content/history/history-panel.xul
chrome://browser/content/bookmarks/bookmarksPanel.xul
```

So far ive tried the normal way using Tabs.api

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "chrome://*" })
```

Apperantly tabs wont take anything that is not "http(s)://", and opening a dummy page with a script to redirect like so

```
window.location.href = "chrome://*"
```

doesn't work either. I get the following error message:

```
Error: Access to 'chrome://browser/content/history/history-panel.xul' from script denied
```

I think I do have all the necessary permissions in my manifest.json though:

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "*://browser/content/history/history-panel.xul"
]
```

I tried Content Security Settings as well, but

```
chrome://*
```

does't work, and neither does

```
*://*
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out its impossible to open .xul with an webExtension. This functionality was deprecated quite a while ago due to security concerns.

Comment: That's correct, WebExtensions cannot open xul pages.